# GIS related scripting

Tags: geotiff-tiff

This might not be strictly GIS related, but here goes.

I am looking for a script (DOS based) or application (Windows) that does the following:

In a filesystem there are a collection of raster maps, for instance 2528aa_2008_ed1.tif, which gives the geographic location of the map, the year issued, and the edition.

We then receive new maps, so that for instance we now receive a map that is 2528aa_2010_ed3.tif.

The script or application must look at the file names in the folders and replace 2528aa_2008_ed1.tif with 2528aa_2010_ed3.tif, so that the folder now only contains the new updated map.

Has anyone had to do this, or can anyone give me guidance on scripts or applications out there that can do this.

Comment: Can there be several editions for the same year, 2010_ed3 and 2010_ed4? Are the parts of fixed length, always 4 digit+2 letters, four digits, two letters and digit? Can there exceptions like "252aa_2010_ed10.tif"?

Comment: Yes, there can be several editions in the same year, but it is very uncommon, as the maps here are updated once every two or so years.  The filenames are always the same length.  And no exeptions, it will always be 2528aa for instance.  There can however be 2528ab, but that is always a different file.

Comment: The most important part, however, is 2528aa_2008......

Comment: Would it be OK for you to do it with SQLite/Spatialite? If it is OK, would you prefer to work with all command line scripts or with GUI from Spatialite-gui?

Comment: This is not really a GIS question as you say.  It is a simple programming question.  If you used simple file names without the extra part (_2010_ed2 etc) your file system could have done it for you by simply replacing with the newer files.  With that extra part, as it is so bespoke, you will need to script a solution.  However, it should be easy to achieve this in any language of your choice by iterating over the filenames, parsing them and/or using regular expressions plus a double check on file modified date to be safe.

Comment: but this question is about geographical metadata